# Programmatically Adding a TreeViewItem

Tags: xaml, uwp, treeview

I'm trying to programmatically populate a treeview in UWP. However, I'm getting confused between `TreeViewItem` and `TreeViewNode`.

I can add a `TreeViewNode` to another `TreeViewNode` like this:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewNode node = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewNode();
node.Content = myInfo.Name;

parentNode.Children.Add(node);
```

However, my understanding is that when I get down to the lowest level, I need a TreeViewItem; e.g.:

```
root
- Level 1 - Node
  - Level 2 - Node
  - Level 2 - Node
    - TreeViewItem?
- Level 1
  - TreeViewItem?
```

However, I can't do this:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewItem node = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewItem();
node.Content = data;
node.Tag = tagInfo;
parentNode.Children.Add(node);
```

I assume that I'm misunderstanding the purpose of a TreeViewItem.  Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the thing is... as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) the **TreeViewItem** is the Root of the **TreeView Item Template** and the **TreeViewNode** is the "actual" Item.

**Oversimplified**

- IF you want to add items to your TreeView, then you HAVE to use the **TreeViewNode** class
- IF you want to "redesign" your TreeViewNodes, lets say instead of normal hierarchical list look you want to have some hexagon list, then you have to implement the **TreeViewItem** in your Style/Template

Comment: So I can add a TreeViewNode to a TreeViewItem, but not the other way around?

Comment: @CuriousDev nah. I edited my answer. Basically ALWAYS use the TreeViewNode if you want to play with Elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zer0 said, you don't have to use `TreeViewItem`. In fact, the basic component that makes up a TreeView is the `TreeViewNode`. The `TreeViewItem` can be thought of as a `TreeViewNode` container of the same level and style. It has the `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` properties, which can create the same *"TreeViewNode"* in batches according to the data collection.

The relationship between `TreeView`/`TreeViewItem`/`TreeViewNode` is like the relationship of **building**/**wall**/**brick**. The wall is made up of many identical bricks and can itself be seen as a large brick.

Best regards.